# Using inline data on a custom map in amcharts_4

Tags: json, amcharts

I've created a custom JSON map from the usaLow map to create regions.  Everything works as expected except when I try to use online data to change a custom description field.  The custom polygon set won't read the inline data.  I'm using my own ids, along the lines of "CMI-SW", "CMI-SE", etc.  I added a "description" property and it will display that, but will not overwrite it in the polygon template.

The examples are directly from the amcharts tutorial site.  It works fine for maps that came with the amcharts_4 download.

```
// Create map instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4maps.MapChart);

// Set map definition
chart.geodata = am4geodata_worldLow;

// Set projection
 chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();
// Set projection
// chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Orthographic();
// chart.panBehavior = "rotateLongLat";

chart.seriesContainer.cursorOverStyle = am4core.MouseCursorStyle.grab;
chart.seriesContainer.cursorDownStyle = am4core.MouseCursorStyle.grabbing;

// Add zoom control
chart.zoomControl = new am4maps.ZoomControl();

var home = chart.chartContainer.createChild(am4core.Button);
home.label.text = "Home";
home.align = "right";
home.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  chart.goHome();
});

chart.backgroundSeries.mapPolygons.template.polygon.fill = am4core.color("#ffffff");
chart.backgroundSeries.mapPolygons.template.polygon.fillOpacity = 0.1;

// Series for World map
 var worldSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
 worldSeries.useGeodata = true;

 worldSeries.data = [{
   id: "US",
   disabled: true
 }, {
  "id": "CA",
  "color": am4core.color("#3F4B3B"),
  "description": "Canada is a North American country stretching from the U.S. in the south to the Arctic Circle in the north. Major cities include massive / // Toronto, west coast film centre Vancouver, French-speaking Montréal and Québec City, and capital city Ottawa. Canada's vast swaths of wilderness include lake-filled Banff National Park in the Rocky Mountains. It's also home to Niagara Falls, a famous group of massive waterfalls."
}, {
  "id": "MX",
  "color": am4core.color("#3F4B3B"),
  "description": "Mexico is a country between the U.S. and Central America that's known for its Pacific and Gulf of Mexico beaches and its diverse landscape of mountains, deserts and jungles. Ancient ruins such as Teotihuacán and the Mayan city of Chichén Itzá are scattered throughout the country, as are Spanish colonial-era towns. In capital Mexico City, upscale shops, renowned museums and gourmet restaurants cater to modern life."
}];

 var polygonTemplateWorld = worldSeries.mapPolygons.template;
 polygonTemplateWorld.tooltipHTML = "{id}";
 polygonTemplateWorld.fill = am4core.color("#74B266");
 polygonTemplateWorld.description = "description";

 polygonTemplateWorld.events.on("hit", hit); 

 var hsWorld = polygonTemplateWorld.states.create("hover");
  hsWorld.properties.fill = am4core.color("#367B25");

 // Series for United States map
 var usaSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
 usaSeries.geodata = am4geodata_usaLow
 usaSeries.useGeodata = true;

 usaSeries.data = [{
"id": "US-AZ",
"color": am4core.color("#3F4B3B"),
 "description": "Yeah, I'm from Tucson!"
 }];

 var polygonTemplateUS = usaSeries.mapPolygons.template;
 polygonTemplateUS.tooltipHTML = "{id}";
 polygonTemplateUS.fill = am4core.color("#74B266");

 polygonTemplateUS.events.on("hit", hit); 

 var hsUS = polygonTemplateUS.states.create("hover");
 hsUS.properties.fill = am4core.color("#367B25");

 // Series for United States map
 var CMIRegionalSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
 CMIRegionalSeries.geodata = am4geodata_usaLowCMIRegional
 CMIRegionalSeries.useGeodata = true;

 CMIRegionalSeries.data = [{
"id": "CMI-SC",
"color": am4core.color("#3F4B3B"),
 "description": "Yeah, I like Sweet Tea!"
 }];

 var polygonTemplateRegion = CMIRegionalSeries.mapPolygons.template;
 polygonTemplateRegion.tooltipHTML = "{name}";
 polygonTemplateRegion.fill = am4core.color("#74B266");

 polygonTemplateRegion.events.on("hit", hit); 

 var hsReg = polygonTemplateRegion.states.create("hover");
 hsReg.properties.fill = am4core.color("#367B25");



 // chart.legend = new am4maps.Legend();
 // chart.legend.position = "left";

/* Events */

function hit(ev) {
//  chart.zoomToMapObject(ev.target);
  var data = ev.target.dataItem.dataContext;
  var popupContent = "";
  if (data.description) {
    popupContent += data.description;
  }
  else {
    popupContent += "<i>No description provided.</i>";
  }
  chart.closeAllPopups();
  chart.openPopup(popupContent,"<strong>" + "<h3>" + data.name + " (" + data.id  + ")</h3>" + "</strong>");
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!